# SQL joining identical tables

Tags: sql

```
select
  person.adresse,
  person.fornavn,
  person.postnr,
  COUNT(PERSON.personnr)
from 
  PERSON 
    inner join 
  POST
    on POST.postnr = PERSON.postnr
    inner join
  PERSON as P 
    on PERSON.adresse = P.adresse
group by 
  PERSON.adresse, 
  PERSON.fornavn,
  PERSON.postnr
having 
  COUNT(PERSON.personnr) > 1
```

Adresse = address, fornavn = first name
I need to show the adress, first name and postal number for persons, where more than one person lives on the same adress. I know it has something to do with joining identical tables, but i can't seem to figure out which tables it would make sense to join.

Comment: can you post Table Structure and what type of Data you want ?

Comment: @JohnWoo I guess i've forgotten to set them as answered, because all 8 of my questions has been answered fully.

Comment: @MoizKachwala Sure: PERSON: Personnr = smallint (PK), Firstname = nvarchar(20), Adress = nvarchar(30), Postnr = smallint (FK).

Comment: @MoizKachwala POST: postnr = smallint (PK)

Answer (score 0):

A straight fix for your query is to add the condition `and PERSON.fornavn <> P.fornavn` which serves to make sure you are joining to a **different** person on the same address.  You can then drop the COUNT especially since it will produce the wrong result.

```
select person.adresse, person.fornavn, person.postnr
from PERSON
join PERSON as P on PERSON.adresse = P.adresse and PERSON.fornavn <> P.fornavn
group by PERSON.adresse, PERSON.fornavn, PERSON.postnr
order by PERSON.adresse
```

While this works, it is probably more efficient to first find the addresses that have more than one person, and then retrieving the persons at those addresses.

```
SELECT P.adresse, P.fornavn, P.postnr
  FROM (
       SELECT adresse
         FROM PERSON
     GROUP BY adresse
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) G
  JOIN PERSON P ON P.adresse = G.adresse
```

Comment: what if there are two people with the same first name at the same address?

Comment: Thanks! We hadn't learned about the <> function that you are using, so it helped me out a great deal.

Comment: Wouldn't your two queries return different results in this case, with the second one being correct? Assuming there's only one person record per person.